# SceneKit Error: C3DMeshElementSetPrimitives invalid index buffer size

Tags: ios, scenekit

I have got the following error :

```
[SceneKit] Error: C3DMeshElementSetPrimitives invalid index buffer size
```

It appears at every frame (many errors !)

Do you know how to solve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you building a custom `SCNGeometry` programmatically?

Comment: Probably your geometryElement has more indices then geometrySource has data

Comment: getting the same error since High Sierra.  haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Check that indices array is paring the vertices in the vertices array properly.

Suppose you wanted to draw a square using lines with 4 vertices like this:

```
         v1 ------ v0
          |        |
          |        |         
         v2 ------ v3
```

The vertices array would be v0, v1, v2, v3.

The lines pairs would be: (v0,v1) , (v1,v2) , (v2,v3) , (v3,v0)

So indices array would be: 0,1,1,2,2,3,3,0

In code, this is an example that draws a node that contains a red circle using lines:

```
func circlePathNode() -> SCNNode {
    
    var vertices:[SCNVector3] = []
    let N = 200
    var indices:[Int16] = []
    
    // vertices
    for i in 1...N {
        
        let t = (Float(i-1) / Float(N)) * 2 * .pi
        
        let v = SCNVector3(cos(t), sin(t), 0)
        
        vertices.append(v)
    }
    
    // indices pair vertices
    for i in 1...N-1 {
        indices.append(Int16(i-1))
        indices.append(Int16(i))
    }
    // last:
    indices.append(Int16(N-1))
    indices.append(0)
    
    let verticesSource = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: vertices)
    
    let indexData = Data(bytes: indices, count: indices.count * MemoryLayout<Int16>.size) // 2 for 2 bytes each 
    let element = SCNGeometryElement(data: indexData,
                                     primitiveType: .line,
                                     primitiveCount: N,
                                     bytesPerIndex: MemoryLayout<Int16>.size)
    
    let geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [verticesSource],elements: [element])
    
    #if os(iOS)
    geometry.firstMaterial?.emission.contents = UIColor.red
    #else 
    geometry.firstMaterial?.emission.contents = NSColor.red
    #endif
    
    return SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when i accidentally pass index count to primitive count. Make sure that you pass exactly primitive count parameter (not index count) to primitive count parameter of `SCNGeometryElement` constructor.

Primitive count can be calculated this way:

```
  func calculatePrimintiveCount( indexCount: Int, primitiveType: SCNGeometryPrimitiveType) -> Int {
    switch (primitiveType){
        case .triangles: return indexCount / 3
        case .triangleStrip: return indexCount - 2
        case .line: return indexCount / 2
        case .point: return indexCount
        case .polygon: return indexCount / 4 // not sure
    }
}
```